# How to trigger an SNS event from withing Twilio

Tags: amazon-web-services, twilio

Is there a way from the GUI (Studio) of Twilio to generte a call to push a notification to an SNS topic on AWS?

Comment: Can you clarify your question with more detail. I see push and call in the same sentence. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Not sure how to phrase it, but when a user selects an option from a prompt, and presses 1, I want this to push to a specific  SNS topic the phone number of the person who pressed n#1 on his phone pad.

Comment: Yes, you can do this but you need to use the Studio Run Function widget, https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/run-function, which will allow you to require the aws-sdk library, and following the steps here - Publishing Messages in Amazon SNS - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sns-examples-publishing-messages.html.